# Using aws-cli can I retrieve files from a CloudFront URL instead of my S3 directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I am using CloudFront-backed S3 to store lots (sometimes gigs) of images and videos on client sites, and for developers to debug issues sometimes you just need the whole set of images.

We use awscli to sync files down, and it works fine.

But, if instead of pulling from S3 I could pull from the CloudFront url, the download would be much faster as well as using less of our outbound S3 data.

Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe:

- A command or flag I just don't know about?
- Rewriting the S3 url on the fly?
- Outputting a list of files that *would* be downloaded, so I can script `curl`ing them?
- Using the `cf` command to do something?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 outbound data pricing (to the Internet) is free for the first 1 GB, then $0.09 for the first 10 TB. Amazon CloudFront pricing is $0.085 for the first 10 GB (US) up to $0.25 (South America).

Even using CloudFront caching, you are only going to save $.005 per GB. Lets say that you transfer 100 GB per month. You will save $.41 (41 cents) by downloading from CloudFront instead of S3. One benefit of CloudFront is usually faster downloads.

You could write a program, such as Python, that lists the objects in an S3 bucket / directory and then generate the equivalent path using CloudFront. Or a simple word search and replace script.

Comment: S3 download pricing is not $0.09/GB across regions.  São Paulo buckets cost $0.25/GB for a direct S3 download, the same as the CloudFront price.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. You are correct. However, the point that I was trying to establish is that the savings are relatively small. Imagine paying for software development that might save $6.00 per year that cost X dollars per man hour to develop and maintain. Sort of like renting a forklift or crane to deliver a small package.

Comment: Agreed, cost savings is not generally an appropriate motivation (although there are quirks in the pricing plan that allow some arbitrage opportunity) I took your comment to mean that CloudFront represented a higher cost.  Performance is a reasonable motivation,  as can be S3 Transfer Acceleration, though that option is notably more expensive than either S3 direct, or S3 via CloudFront.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of developer productivity - if I can save 45 mins a week of dev time downloading a ton of assets (CDN vs S3), it's worth it -- if this is a simple thing to do (a little `awk`+`curl` magic, or a trick in the `aws-cli`). If I'm maintaining a separate app, yeah the savings get eaten up fast :)

Comment: May be you can consider something like AWS Storage Gateway.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, downloading data from cloudfront will be more expensive as that would be on http/https while when we download data from S3 it is local ( if u create endpoint ).

Also, if u are thinking to download lots of image via cloudfront; do not think it will be faster; because for each request it will go to cloudfront and that image will not be found there and will go to origin which is S3.

Hence, you will end up in paying more money and bad latency.

Comment: Downloads are going out to developer's local machines, distributed around the US. They are not going to EC2 instances. Is that what you mean by local?

Comment: @PrernaSinghal, this isn't accurate for downloads outside of EC2.  Download bandwidth through CloudFront is often slightly lower in cost, even on cache misses, because there is no transport charge from S3 to CloudFront.  It also usually faster because it optimizes the transport path, again, even on cache misses.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If we are downloading to outside AWS framework; yes I agree it optimises the path but I do not agree still it will be faster than downloading directly from S3 bucket for cache-misses.

Comment: @PrernaSinghal that's what S3 Transfer Acceleration is -- S3 through CloudFront with caching disabled.  If the bucket is close to you, it will not make a difference, but the further away the bucket is, the more it will help improve performance by keeping as much of the traffic as possible on the optimized networks controlled by AWS.